# Issue with google library in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, google-chrome, google-cloud-platform

I am running into an error when importing the below library

```
from google.cloud import vision
```

The error message I receive is :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "d:/UnmatchedOTMProcess/ImageDetection_test.py", line 2, in <module>
from google.cloud import vision
File "C:\Users\mhancock\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\google\cloud\vision.py", line 
17, in <module>
from google.cloud.vision_v1 import ImageAnnotatorClient
File "C:\Users\mhancock\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site- 
packages\google\cloud\vision_v1\__init__.py", line 27, in <module>
from google.cloud.vision_v1.gapic import image_annotator_client as iac
File "C:\Users\mhancock\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site- 
packages\google\cloud\vision_v1\gapic\image_annotator_client.py", line 24, in <module>
import google.api_core.gapic_v1.client_info
File "C:\Users\mhancock\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site- 
packages\google\api_core\gapic_v1\__init__.py", line 16, in <module>
from google.api_core.gapic_v1 import config
File "C:\Users\mhancock\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site- 
packages\google\api_core\gapic_v1\config.py", line 23, in <module>
import grpc
File "C:\Users\mhancock\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\grpc\__init__.py", line 23, in 
<module>
from grpc._cython import cygrpc as _cygrpc
ImportError: cannot import name 'cygrpc' from 'grpc._cython' 
(C:\Users\mhancock\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\grpc\_cython\__init__.py)
```

The code works perfectly on my local machine, however trying to run this on a gcp virtual machine and the environment must be slightly different somehow.

Appreciate any assistance!

Thanks in advance,
Matt

Comment: Do you run it on Windows VM? Did you have python installed? If so, what is the version?

Comment: Welcome Matt! Please take a look on [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and provide us with a minimal reproducible example of your code. Also please keep in mind that this library only works with 64 bit Python, make sure that you have this Python installed in your vm environment

Comment: Personally I had lot of issues with python 3.8 and GCP libraries please try with latest python 3.7

If you are using the preinstalled python on the VM please uninstall python and GCloud SDK and  manually install latest python 2.7, latest python 3.7 and Gcloud SDK in that order

Comment: Update I used a virtualenv in a Windows GCE instance with python 3.7.7 and all works as is expected.